# Creating Batch or Shell File from G++ Compiled Output Instead of .exe

Tags: batch-file, g++, sh

I'm trying to change a g++ compiler instruction which is generating an executable (.exe) file to instead generate a batch file. I was unable to find any specific compiler options that I would need to change to be able to do this besides just changing the extension of the output file.
If I just change the file output to be .bat instead of .exe. I will also want to eventually be able to generate a shell file (.sh) as a separate compiler instruction, so any help with this is also appreciated.

When I tried just changing the .exe to be .bat for the file output, the .bat file was encoded using ANSI which made running it through command prompt result in an encoding error (it output random characters on the console output). I tried changing the code page to UTF-8 while running the compile instructions (chcp 65001), and separately changing the code page to ANSI (chcp 1300, but this was invalid in cmd) before running the .bat file, but neither way worked. I'm not sure if there's a flag I can use for g++ to change this.

Below are the compiler instructions I'm trying to change, with output.bat originally being output.exe (The ${} are paths on my device and are valid when I run these instructions, and I've made some of the file paths more generic for privacy).

```
${GCC_COMPILER}/g++  -c -DCLB_SIM -I${SYSTEMC_INSTALL}/src -I${ROOT_DIR}/headers -I${PROJECT_ROOT} -I${GCC_COMPILER}/include -Og -g -gdwarf-3 -gstrict-dwarf -Wall -MMD -MP -MF${BuildDirectory}/genFile/output.d -MT${BuildDirectory}/genFile/output.o -I${BuildDirectory}/headers   -fno-threadsafe-statics  -o${BuildDirectory}/genFile/output.o ${BuildDirectory}/source.cpp

${GCC_COMPILER}/g++ -DCLB_SIM -Og -g -gdwarf-3 -gstrict-dwarf -Wall -Wl,-Map,${BuildDirectory}/genFile/output.map -L${SYSTEMC_INSTALL}/build/src -o${BuildDirectory}/genFile/output.bat ${BuildDirectory}/simulation/output.o ${ROOT_DIR}/firstObject.o ${ROOT_DIR}/secondObject.o ${ROOT_DIR}/thirdObject.o -Wl,--start-group -lsystemc -Wl,--end-group
```

My expected goal is that I can run these compile instructions to generate a .bat or .sh (obviously on Windows and Linux respectively, as separate instances), and then immediately after I can run the .bat/.sh file with the respective instruction (such as "output.bat" for Windows). These instructions themselves will be in a .bat/.sh file, but I feel that I may be doing this incorrectly and these instructions should be in a makefile (although I'm not sure what this would change, but let me know the proper convention for this). Basically, I'm creating a primary.bat file that will compile another output.bat file which should be able to be executed within the primary.bat file, but the issue is that I can't do this and instead I need to double-click it within the directory to run output.bat.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Both BAT and sh files are *plain text files* that contain commands that are interpreted by cmd or sh, respectively. This is fundamentally different from a compiled executable file that's generated by GCC. Changing the file extension does not turn one into the other. What is the problem you are trying to solve?